# When does a homotopy exist?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, homotopy-extension-property

Let $X\coprod X$ be the disjoint union of $X$ with itself and let there be a commutative square

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X \coprod X @>{f,g}>> A  \\
@V{(i_0, i_1)}VV  @VV{p}V  \\
X \times I  @>>{k}> B
\end{CD}
$$

where $p$ is a Serre fibration and weak homotopy equivalence.
Is it true that this diagram admits a lift $h: X \rightarrow A$ ? (In other words, is $X \times I$ a cylinder object for any $X$?). I know this is true for CW-complexes, but I think it holds for any topological space.

Comment: I believe the only fact about CW complexes you would use in proving this is that the inclusion into the cylinder is a cofibration, but this is true for all spaces since it is clear that $X \times \{0\} \cup X \times \{1\}$ is a NDR of $X \times I$.

Comment: I wrote something wrong, a need that both the top triangle and bottom triagle commute, in  what a read about what you said implies the existence of lift making to top commute, but can we take such homotopy to make the bottom traingle commute?

Comment: Let $A$ be any space and take $p$ to be the unique map to a point. Then $f,g$ can be arbitrary maps and there is no reason why they should be homotopic. Clearly in general there is no reason why a diagonal should exist.

Comment: In this case $p$ wouldn't be serre fibration.

Comment: Yes, it would be. It would even be a Hurewicz fibration.

Comment: Oh, I read you coment wrong sorry

Comment: You are right, a i need to take $p$ to be a weak homotopy equivalence.

Comment: Do you know that the category of topogical spaces has a (closed) model structure with "cofibrations" = pushouts of inclusions of subcomplexes of CW-complexes, "fibrations" = Serre fibrations and "weak equivalences" = weak homotopy equivalences?